# What type of gift card do I need to purchase in order to get a digital copy of Garden Warfare 2?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare-2

I want to purchase Garden Warfare 2. What type of gift card do I need to buy to get the game  on a Windows 10 machine?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, Garden Warfare 2 is only available for Windows through [Origin](https://www.origin.com/), so you'd need an Origin gift card.  In the US, you can [buy these at Game Stop](http://www.gamestop.com/pc/in-game-currency/ea-origins-20-game-card/116418), among other retailers.

Note that there are two editions of the game:

- [Standard Edition](https://www.origin.com/usa/en-us/store/plants-vs-zombies/plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare-2/standard-edition), MSRP $19.99 USD
- [Deluxe Edition](https://www.origin.com/usa/en-us/store/plants-vs-zombies/plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare-2/deluxe-edition), MSRP $29.99 USD

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends, for console in America you would need a 20$ Xbox card, for PC then Origin.

[Playstation](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP0006-CUSA01975_00-PVZGW2BASEGAME00): 20$

[Xbox 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare-2/bnrh7brc1d02) : 20$

[Origin (PC)](https://www.origin.com/usa/en-us/store/plants-vs-zombies/plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare-2) : 20-30$

So depending on the system you are using, buy the gift card that matches the price of the game on your selected system